# How can I add date come from phpmyadmin to java jtable as change date format

Tags: date, phpmyadmin, format, jtable, addition

I am adding a date to my phpmyadmin database. phpadmin save it default "yyyy.mm.dd". Then I get that data to Jtable. I may convert format if I save as String type to jtable.("dd.mm.yyyy"). but I can't sort date this time. My problem is how can ı get date values from the database ("yyyy.mm.dd") and add to java jtable's rows as date type ("dd.mm.yyyy" format) thanks for your helpful

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have done so far? 


Please refer to
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi. I try to this.  I save 24.03.2019 to phpmyadmin. phpadmin default is 2019.03.24. and I want to select this date and add to java jtable as date format. But it is shown like 2019.03.24. I want 24.03.2019 format. (not as string. because cant sort this way). I hope  I explained. Thanks your reply

Comment: What I meant was can you add the minimal code (i.e. smallest code) that you currently have that creates the problem. FWIW, Dates are **not** stored in databases with a specific format. Dates (and times and timestamps) are stored as a number of (days, seconds or milliseconds) from a particular point in time. For examples todays date in unix epoch format is 1557886394. Formatting is something that is applied on input or output to convert that number from or to something like this "15-May" (dd-mmm) or 2019/05/15 (yyyy-mm-dd) and so on.

Comment: Showing us your code is the best way to enable people to help you.